# error The method onClick(DialogInterface, int) of type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){} should be tagged with @Override

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have an Android project in Eclipse IDE got import
.This was error
.Details:==>>api-10

error

> The method onClick(DialogInterface, int) of type new 
>       DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}
>       should be tagged with @Override since it actually overrides a superinterface method

Code:

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(final int id) {
    LayoutInflater.from(this);
    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_IMPORT_FILE:
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_upload)
                    .setTitle(R.string.import_file)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.import_file, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                            File f = mSelectedFile;
                            Intent i = new Intent(mContext, ImportSudokuActivity.class);
                            Uri u = Uri.fromFile(f);
                            i.setData(u);
                            startActivity(i);
                            //finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
                    .create();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have add **@Override** above Your Dialog's onClick Method because Dialog superclass already has onClick Method defined. You have to override it.

so change your code like this.

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
```

to

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
```